# How to fix a French drain

Tags: french-drain

We have an interior French drain around the complete perimeter of our basement and has been working fine for 18 years until December 2020. I should note the company that put it in is no longer in business.

The 3 inch pvc pipe was placed underneath the foundation of the house with holes on the bottom and sits on a silt sleeve. Weep holes were drilled in the block at the bottom of the air gap membrane. It drains to two pump wells located in the corners.

Note: When researching issues on this site I realize a different type of pipe is recommended as well as an air gap membrane curves over top of the pipe and crushed stone. My air gap membrane does not seem to cover the pipe. I am attaching pictures from when the work was done and from today. This is the only spot that failed and it’s about 3 feet.

Any recommendations on how to address this?
Can I drill holes behind the air gap membrane? The water in this section is not draining to the pipe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before you do anything else, I would check the waterproofing/drainage in the window well. Seems suspicious that the only place you’re having water issues is right below and adjacent to the light well.